Null vector does not depend on operations
Let S be a set and K a field. Is the following statement valid?
If $V_1$ is a vector space constructed over K using S as its set of vectors (i.e. $(S,+ _1,._1)$ ) and $V_2$ is another vector space constructed in the same way with diferent operations (i.e. $(S,+ _2,._2)$ ) $\Rightarrow$ $\theta{}_1 = \theta{}_2$ (where $\theta{}_1$ is the null vector of $V_1$ and $\theta{}_2$ is the null vector of $V_2$).
(This is $(S,+ _1,._1)$ and $(S,+ _2,._2)$ are vector spaces $\Rightarrow$ $\theta{}_1 = \theta{}_2$ )
It’s easy to see that if $._1 = ._2 \Rightarrow \theta_1 = 0_K ._1 v = 0_K ._2 v = \theta_2$ (where $0_K$ is the zero of the field).
And in the same way if $+_1 = +_2 \Rightarrow \theta_1 = \theta_1 +_1 \theta_2 = \theta_1 +_2 \theta_2 = \theta_2$
But I could not find neither a counterexample for both nor a proof.

This is false.
To see an example, simply take one vector space structure, $(V,+,\cdot)$, and take a bijection $f\colon V\to V$ that does not send $\mathbf{0}$ to itself. Then use transport of structure to define a new vector space structure on $V$. This will make the additive identity of the new structure equal to $f^{-1}(\mathbf{0})$, which by assumption is not equal to $\mathbf{0}$.
For instance, take $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over itself with the usual addition and multiplication, and $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $f(x)=x+1$. We use this to define a new addition $\oplus$ and a new scalar multiplication $\odot$ as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
a\oplus b &= f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b)) = a+b+1\\
r\odot a &= f^{-1}(r\cdot f(a)) = ra+r-1
\end{align*}$$
This makes $(\mathbb{R},\oplus,\odot)$ into a real vector space, with zero vector equal to $-1$.

Thanks, that would solve the problem
